# How start and install apk to specific android emulator by Gradle?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Gradle 2.14

If I want to install the application to the connected device I use the next command:

```
gradlew installDebug
```

OK.
But also I have 4 emulators (not started). I want by one gradle command to START emulator **my_emulator_name** and install my application to this emulator. Something like this:

```
gradlew installDebug my_emulator_name
```

Is this a possible?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the same thing. I also asked ChatGPT but didn't get a working answer. Gradle tasks can be defined with code so you could make your own, or maybe there is a way to do it with the [android gradle tasks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/tools_r22/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy#1096). I'm not seeing simple options there..

I know this is not the answer but it will achieve the same result. Assemble an apk and install it with `adb -s`. For example:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
real-device device
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
$ ./gradlew my-app:assembleDebug
$ adb -s emulator-5554 install -r my-app/build/outputs/apk/debug/my-app.apk
```